# Seaside - What's the point of implementing #children in a WAComponent when a direct call to "html render:" is made in "renderContentOn: html"?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

```
Whatever >> children
        ^Array with: oneComponent with: anotherComponent.
```

Later in the code one might have something like this.

```
Whatever >> renderContentOn: html
        ...
        html render: oneComponent.
        ...
        html render: anotherComponent.
```

Since I make a call explicitly to render these components, what's the use of having them in #children? Is #children used for anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seaside depends on `#children` being correctly implemented for the following callbacks:

- `#updateRoot:` to customise the head section of the generated HTML document,
- `#initialRequest:` to initialise the component at the beginning of a session,
- `#updateUrl:` to modify the current URL,
- `#updateStates:` to registers objects for backtracking,
- as well as to support helper methods like `#states`, `#scripts`, and `#styles`.

Search the [Seaside Book](http://book.seaside.st) for these methods to learn more about them.

Comment: Lukas is spot on with the features that require `#children` (though embedded `WATask` objects should also be mentioned). If you're interested in more detail about why the implementation is as it is, I [wrote in some depth](http://blog.fitzell.ca/2014/10/declaring-seaside-sub-components-in-children.html) about this a few months ago in response to a question on the seaside mailing list.

Comment: @Julian I've only now seen your comment. Interesting! I've added you to my "watching" blog list.